# How to stretch the background of the block to the full width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, layout, position, css-position

This is a common case in a layout. I need the content width to be 1170 pixels and the content to be centered on the page. However, in some cases I want to stretch the blocks to the full width. How do I do it right?
There is my example:

```
<div class="page__wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        <!-- .header__header-content.header-content>.header-content__header-top.header-top -->
        <div class="wrapper-try1"><div class="wrapper-try1__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio labore debitis voluptates quisquam, earum nemo, ipsam consequuntur cum rem, sint, nulla repellendus. Repellendus ea distinctio similique fuga dolores consequatur minima..</div></div>

        <div class="try2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo autem et nihil consequuntur incidunt veritatis est, earum deleniti vel rem. Minus ad, tenetur enim repellendus molestias vel possimus voluptas alias soluta atque eum officia facilis quia magni recusandae expedita, vitae numquam porro ipsum repudiandae. Ipsam perspiciatis est unde laboriosam eligendi.</div>
    </header>

</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.page__wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.wrapper-try1__content,
.try2{
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper-try1{
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper-try1__content{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

It's should looks like this:

[image: HTML Page]

Comment: It seems you have different screen size and based on certain size you need you div to take certain size and location so have you thought about @media take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one change can resolve this:

```
.wrapper-try1__content,
.try2{
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want different width in different size of window like mobile devices etc. then you can use media query css like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .wrapper-try1__content,
    .try2{
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

For more info please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries